# venv doesn't appear to be getting used by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I have Python installed on the Mac. If I run `python -V` it outputs `3.7.2`

If I run the following:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -V
```

I see `3.7.2`.

If I try to run `nose` I get this error:

```
$ nosetests -s -v config_test.test_config:TestConfiguration
Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'boto3') ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'boto3')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 675, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config/config_test/config_sdk.py", line 4, in <module>
import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I'm immediately concerned with the `3.6` references.

If I then run `pip install boto3` I can see the package when I run `pip list` however I get the same error as above when I try running my applicaiton again.

I've tried `pyenv global 3.7.2` and `pyenv local 3.7.2` but neither makes any difference.

Can anybody suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have an alias defined for python? I remember having trouble with an alias inside virtualenv. Maybe try renaming that alias and try source your .bashrc/.zshrc/.bash_profile/whatever ... again, before sourcing your virtualenv. Also try `type python` (this also tells you what your alias stands for, in case you use an alias).
`type py` outputs `py is an alias for python3`

Comment: And if `nose` is installed in the environment what does `which python` command report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nose` wasn't installed in the venv. After I installed it with `pip install nose` I had to deactivate the venv and reactivate it.